# Count and sum of value in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table in Access which I want to create query from. I want to count how many times value 1 occurred in 1st column, how many times value 2 occurred in 2nd column etc.

```
ID  Col1    Col2    Col3  Col4
-------------------------------
172  1   2   4   3
172  3   2   4   1
173  2   3   5   4
173  2   1   3   4
```

Output (Count of value occurrences):

```
             1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
             ------------------------------
172  1st     1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
172  2nd     0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
172  3rd     0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0
172  4th     1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
173  1st     0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
173  2nd     1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
173  3rd     0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
173  4th     0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
Total Count  3   2   4   3   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: This seems like it would be more appropriate to do in a programming language, operating on a two dimensional array

Comment: `Pivot` and `Transform` are your friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using MS-Access, you could use a query like this:

```
TRANSFORM Count([s].[ID]) AS Counts
SELECT [s].ID, [s].[tbl]
FROM (
     SELECT ID, '1st' AS tbl, [1st] AS Val FROM yourtable
     UNION ALL SELECT ID, '2st' AS tbl, [2nd] AS Val FROM yourtable
     UNION ALL SELECT ID, '3st' AS tbl, [3rd] AS Val FROM yourtable
     UNION ALL SELECT ID, '4st' AS tbl, [4th] AS Val FROM yourtable

)  AS [s]
GROUP BY [s].ID, [s].[tbl]
PIVOT [s].[Val];
```

If you also want the totals, you can use this one:

```
TRANSFORM Count([s].[ID]) AS Counts
SELECT [s].ID, [s].[tbl]
FROM (SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT ID, '1st' AS tbl, [1st] AS Val FROM yourtable
     UNION ALL SELECT ID, '2st' AS tbl, [2nd] AS Val FROM yourtable
     UNION ALL SELECT ID, '3st' AS tbl, [3rd] AS Val FROM yourtable
     UNION ALL SELECT ID, '4st' AS tbl, [4th] AS Val FROM yourtable)
  UNION ALL
   SELECT 999 AS ID, 'Total' AS tbl, Val FROM (
      SELECT ID, '1st' AS tbl, [1st] AS Val FROM yourtable
     UNION SELECT ID, '2st' AS tbl, [2nd] AS Val FROM yourtable
     UNION SELECT ID, '3st' AS tbl, [3rd] AS Val FROM yourtable
     UNION SELECT ID, '4st' AS tbl, [4th] AS Val FROM yourtable)
)  AS [s]
GROUP BY [s].ID, [s].[tbl]
PIVOT [s].[Val];
```

Comment: I got "The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize '[1st] ' as a valid field name. I actually used different field name but I got the same error.

Comment: i tested it on Access 2010 and it works, what's your table name? and the names of the columns?

Comment: @user2377055 did you change `yourtable` to the actual name of your table? then you need to change `'1st' AS tbl, [1st] AS Val` as `'Column1' AS tbl, [Column1] AS Val` etc...

Comment: Yes I changed it to my actual table and field names. At first I used, SELECT ID, '1st' AS tbl, [1st] AS Val, it gives me error. But when I changed it to  SELECT ID, '1st' AS tbl, [Tip1] AS Val, it works! Tip1, Tip2 etc are my actual field names. Thanks fthiella. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: it does work but it groups all the values in my table. I'm sorry. it's my fault, I gave wrong sample output. It should be grouped by ID. I have rows 172, 172, 173, 173, 173 etc

Comment: have you tried my sample table? the query you provided does not return any error but produces incorrect count.

Comment: @user2377055 i tried it with your sample table, and it gives the correct result (except that you miss a value in ID 179, and instead of 0s you get nulls but that's easy to fix), what do you mean that it has to be grouped by ID?

Comment: I edited the input and output. The rows with the same ID can be more than 4. It could be 5 or more.

Comment: @user2377055 updated my answer, it matches the results and it calculates the total rows correctly

Comment: can I have your email address? I have something off topic to ask.

Comment: @user2377055 it's my username @ gmail.com

Comment: I emailed you. Did you receive it?

Answer (score -1):

**Try Following:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 1st)
      , COUNT(DISTINCT 2nd)
      , COUNT(DISTINCT 3rd)
      , COUNT(DISTINCT 4th)
      , SUM(
            sum(COUNT(DISTINCT 1st))
           ,sum(COUNT(DISTINCT 2nd))
           ,sum(COUNT(DISTINCT 3rd))
           ,sum(COUNT(DISTINCT 4th))
        )  AS Total
  FROM tableName
 GROUP BY     1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th
```

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: I got "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT(1st)),COUNT(DISTINCT(2nd)),COUNT(DISTINCT(3rd)),COUNT(DISTINCT(4th))

Comment: Same error. I think DISTINCT (Fieldname) is not suppported in Access

Comment: @user2377055 just googled, syntax for it is bit different, remove brackets over distinct , go through my edit

Comment: According here: [link] http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp COUNT(DISTINCT) works with ORACLE and Microsoft SQL Server, but not with Microsoft Access. I got error in 1st on row 1 of the query

Comment: @user2377055 its available, see the example http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx

Comment: Yes it's available but the example is somewhat different from my desired output.

Comment: yeah i posted link just to show you it works, its not related to ur question at all

Comment: Oh I see. I'm sorry about that. Why do you think it doesn't work. Access returns error highlighting the 1st in this line SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 1st)

Comment: i cant say firmly, but may be due to column name 1st, we can say this firmly if it will work with count(disctinct ID)

Comment: it won't work in Access. You can SELECT DISTINCT ... but you can't COUNT(DISTINCT ...)